# django-social-auth error in connecting with Facebook

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I have problem in connecting with Facebook backend of django-social-auth. I have created a Facebook app and in my project setting, I have provided its settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social_auth'
) 

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",  
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

LOGIN_URL = "/"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URLNAME = "home"
LOGOUT_URL = "/"

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
    ...
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_EXPIRATION = 'expires'

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '***************'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = '**************'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_photos']
```

In 'Site Url' of my app on Facebook I have provided IP of my PC. Now when I connect with Facebook through my IP with my own account then it works fine. But when I try to connect with some other Facebook account then it give the error  on permissions page:
 "Sorry, something went wrong.We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."
Can someone has any idea?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the configuration you used?

Comment: @Yasel I have edited my question and now this is my all configuration for django-social-auth.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For Facebook backend of django-social-auth to work properly then runserver on your IP instead of running on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

In Facebook each app has certain permissions for Facebook Users, you are the lead developer, you can add testers and what not, Its on the app configuration interface.